# Download all types of files from server using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a file in server .

I want download this file .

I use this code

```
try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;

        if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + file)))
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file);
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(("~/Upload/" + file));
            Response.End();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            {
                Type csType = GetType();
                string jsScript = "alert('File Not Found');";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, csType, "popup", jsScript, true);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMsg = ex.Message;
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "popup", errorMsg, true);
    }
```

But when i use this, I get error

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

in code

> Response.End();

How to download all types of files?

Answer (score 0):

Is this Web Forms, MVC, or a custom IHttpHandler?

In any event, you don't need to call `Response.End()` or `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`, just `return` from your function and ensure nothing else is written to the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is a Web Forms. I remove `Response.End() HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`, I don't get error but don't download file .

Comment: Are you able to debug your code? Can you step-through your code and see if any exceptions are thrown or caught? Consider removing your `try/catch` block.

Comment: Yes I debug it, but  don't any exceptions are thrown or caught.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + file));
```

instead of :

```
Response.WriteFile(("~/Upload/" + file));
```

You should also remove the BufferOutput (bad idea with `Response.End()` without `Response.Flush()`)

Comment: Ah, good catch, I didn't see that buffering was enabled. That explains it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use this `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + file));` but won't download.

Comment: @Niloo You shoud also remove the Response.BufferOutput = true;

Comment: I remove it, but don't download :(